# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Explanation would be appreciated

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I know most of you have probably seen this error a hundred times and a short answer to it would be change the operator = to in, however, that doesn't seem to work with me.

```
UPDATE _RS
SET _RS.GroupID = (SELECT ID FROM _RefSkillGroup WHERE Code like '%SKILL_GODBLESS_%')
FROM _RefSkill _RS
JOIN _RefSkillGroup _RSG 
ON _RS.GroupID=_RSG.ID
WHERE _RS.ID BETWEEN 33816 AND 33824
```

```
UPDATE _RefSkill 
SET GroupID = (SELECT ID FROM _RefSkillGroup WHERE Code LIKE '%SKILL_GODBLESS_%')
WHERE ID BETWEEN 33816 AND 33824
```

That is in _RefSkill:

```
Service ID GroupID Basic_Code 
1 33816 1027 SKILL_GODBLESS_FIRE
1 33817 1028 SKILL_GODBLESS_RED
1 33818 1029 SKILL_GODBLESS_BLUE
1 33819 1030 SKILL_GODBLESS_WHIT
```

And that is in _RefSkillGroup

```
ID Code
1038 SKILL_GODBLESS_FIRE
1039 SKILL_GODBLESS_RED
1040 SKILL_GODBLESS_BLUE
1041 SKILL_GODBLESS_WHIT
```

Comment: The error message says it all. You want to assign a value to your column, but the subqeury returns several values. Which one do you want?

Comment: Thank you Jarlh. I'm trying to update a value in different rows.  

That is in _RefSkill:
Service ID       GroupID   Basic_Code
1 33816 1027 SKILL_GODBLESS_FIRE
1 33817 1028 SKILL_GODBLESS_RED
1 33818 1029 SKILL_GODBLESS_BLUE
1 33819 1030 SKILL_GODBLESS_WHIT


And that is in _RefSkillGroup

ID            Code
1038 SKILL_GODBLESS_FIRE
1039 SKILL_GODBLESS_RED
1040 SKILL_GODBLESS_BLUE
1041 SKILL_GODBLESS_WHIT


What I'm trying to do is to correct the value in the GroupID column in _RefSkill, not for one row but for all the rows following the condition 'SKILL_GODBLESS_%'

Comment: The view is messed. 

Here is a screenshot of my reply
http://prntscr.com/svqlsy

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM _RefSkillGroup WHERE Code like '%SKILL_GODBLESS_%'` returns more than one row.

Comment: Please avoid using the comments to post code (well, at least, long code). Instead, [edit] your question to provide the data. Also, please read and follow the instructions on the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) on how to write a good SQL question.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. I know the query returns more than one row. I want to update the value in all the rows matching that condition, such a thing isn't possible with this syntax?

Comment: added. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please state in plain English, what you want, specifically: what column in what table should be updated, what value should be set there and based on what condition. Expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Right. What I want to do is to update the column GroupID in _RefSkill with the value of ID column in _RefSkillGroup given that the Basic_Code in _RefSkill is the same as Code in _RefSkillGroup.

I hope that is clear to understand :( @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your requirement.

The query is below:

```
UPDATE _RS
-- "update the column GroupID in _RefSkill with the value of ID"
SET _RS.GroupID = _RSG.ID
FROM _RefSkill _RS
    -- You join on a table where you want to look up a value.
    -- "given that the Basic_Code in _RefSkill is the same as Code in _RefSkillGroup"
    JOIN _RefSkillGroup _RSG ON _RS.Basic_Code =_RSG.Code
WHERE _RS.ID BETWEEN 33816 AND 33824
```

Other comments:
I would suggest that you not prefix you table/column names with underscores.

**Update:**

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server) deals with various update join formats

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! It worked and the explanation really helps me alot! 

Is there a way to do that without using the joins?

Comment: No, as you need to copy values from one table to another, you have to join two tables. There are different join formats  available though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be fine with a *correlation* clause instead of a `join`:

```
UPDATE RS
    SET GroupID = (SELECT rsg.ID
                   FROM _RefSkillGroup rsg
                    WHERE rsg.Code LIKE '%SKILL_GODBLESS_%' AND
                          rs.GroupID = rsg.ID
                  )
    FROM _RefSkill RS
    WHERE RS.ID BETWEEN 33816 AND 33824;
```

This assumes that the subquery does, indeed, only return one row for each row in `RS`.  If not, *you* need to figure out which of these rows you want.